# Remeber User Update MasterDetail

Tags: xamarin

I have a master detail VievModel where I am updating the menuEntries once user is logged in, now i have added remember me functionality which works fine. But i have issue with updating the entries, I will explain the steps

1. Users details are remembered
2. User starts the application and is logged in automatically
3. User opens the master detail menu and must click on the SignIn label once he goes through (not signung in) just displays the page and presses the close button then the label Profile is displayed.
   The update is very simple and I debbuged the whole process and once user start the application with hist details remembered the

`bool LoggedIn = true`

Do you have any idea?

```
private void UpdateData()
        {
            if (LoggedUser.LoggedIn)
            {

                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {

                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryUserProfile,
                    Icon = IconsFont.User,
                    CreatePage = () => new UserProfile()

                });
            }
            else if (LoggedUser.LoggedOffline)
            {
                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryUserProfile,
                    Icon = IconsFont.User,
                    CreatePage = () => new UserProfile()

                });

            }
            else 
            {
                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryLoginSignUp,
                    Icon = IconsFont.User,
                    CreatePage = () => new Login()
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is.  Are you saying that when the MD menu is first presented, it acts like the user is NOT logged in when they really are?

Comment: @Jason yes, all his details are displayed, then he clicks on Login and after he the page is present then the MD menu is correct

Comment: Do you want to log user's login information? If loged, navigate to others page. If not, push up a login page, You can use local storage in xamarin forms. There's a great nuget that supports cross-platform storage. For more information https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage Or you can `Application.Current.Properties` implemented in Xamarin.Forms that allow simple Key-Value pairs of data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#Properties_Dictionary